# Calculating combined errors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I am trying to learn to combine errors, but I am confused on how to calculate it once I string it all together into my equation.
The equation is given by 
$$
y = A + (n - n_1) \cdot \frac{B - A}{n_2 - n_1}
$$
and the errors are
\begin{align}
\sigma_{n} &= 0.143 \\
\sigma_{n_1} &= 0.209 \\
\sigma_{n_2} &=1.27 
\end{align}
How would I combine all these errors to work out the total errors for $y$?

My attempt was:
$$
\textrm{Total error} = \sqrt{ \sqrt{n^2 + n_1^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_2^2 + n_1^2}} }
$$
This yields the $1.01$.
But from my actual data there is no way this is correct, that would be many orders of magnitude off from my actual measurements, so it can't be the correct way to calculate the error.

Comment: What are the uncertainties on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: A and B are considered precise without errors for this equation.

Comment: Are the errors independent/uncorrelated?

Comment: @Dale i'm not sure what that means (still very new to this), i guess independent? This is mainly for practising as a beginner. The errors were calculated in python using a Gaussian curve on a graph and i just noted them down.

Comment: WDUK, you should try to develop some intuition for when an answer is correct. Your error estimate is obviously wrong because it doesn't include B-A or the sigmas. Maybe you should try walking before you run. Can you calculate the uncertainty if the equation is y = A*(n-n1)? Or y = n1*n2? Or y = B/n?

Comment: We were told not to consider A and B to have errors. Nor learnt about sigmas yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is

$$f(n,n_1,n_2)=A+(B-A)\frac{n-n_1}{n_2-n_1}$$

The error propagation formula states that the error $\sigma_f$ on this function is given by:

$$\sigma_f=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}\sigma_n\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial n_1}\sigma_{n_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial n_2}\sigma_{n_2}\right)^2}$$

Substituting into this formula will give you the correct error estimate.

**EDIT**:

If you can't take partial derivatives for some reason, then in this particular case, since only addition, subtraction, multiplication and division are involved, you only need to know two rules:

- For adding and subtracting quantities, the **absolute error** on the sum/difference is equal to the **absolute errors** added in quadrature.
- For multiplying and dividing quantities, the **relative error** on the product/quotient is equal to the **relative errors** (e.g. $\sigma_a/a$) added in quadrature.

So, first compute the error on the differences $d_1=n-n_1$ and $d_2=n_2-n_1$. Then use those errors $\sigma_{d_1}$ and $\sigma_{d_2}$ to compute the error on the quotient $\frac{d_1}{d_2}$. The final error will be equal to $(B-A)$ times the error on $\frac{d_1}{d_2}$.

Comment: Are those partial derivatives? Hmm don't think we learn them at high school, now i'm really confused. We've so far only learnt of adding errors in quadrature.

Comment: @WDUK Well, for a function like this, it's always safest to use the full formula, since it always works. That said, there is an alternative method in this particular case if taking partial derivatives isn't possible. Editing now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)